# Optimistic locking failed exception while try to save same row

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
public Long upsertCreditRiskInformation(@Valid CreditRiskInformationCodeTermBasedRequest request, Boolean codeBased)
            throws IOException {
      `CreditRisk creditRisk =` creditRiskDataRepository.findByOrganisationId(organisation.getId());

        if (creditRisk == null) {

            if (codeBased) {

                creditRisk =
                        new CreditRisk(null, creditRiskData, null, getExternalQueryDate(creditRiskData), organisation);
            } else {
                creditRisk =
                        new CreditRisk(creditRiskData, null, getExternalQueryDate(creditRiskData), null, organisation);
            }

        } else {// modify

            creditRisk.modifyCreditRisk(creditRisk, request.getCreditRiskData(), getExternalQueryDate(creditRiskData),
                    codeBased);
        }

        return creditRiskDataRepository.save(creditRisk).getId();
    }
}
```

this is  the method which is called from 2 places at same time.

One sends with `codebased=true`, other is with `false`. So, if it is new creation, both can try to create new.

How can i prevent this?

I used `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)`

top of the method. But this time, error is:

```
    ould not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_jvmwr3y956lfnbk4fhh859cof]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement (Duplicate entry '13' for key 'UK_jvmwr3y956lfnbk4fhh859cof')
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_jvmwr3y956lfnbk4fhh859cof]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I can not understand where is the error. It signals the last line, `repository.save`

Because i do `null check` before, so `lock` does not prevent it. Because null check shows both null, before lock.

What can i do?

Comment: Did you used `spring-data-jpa` or `hibernate` ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna both are `spring-data` . I did not use sql code like `queryhints`

Comment: It pretty hard to say the solution without seeing to full configuration. But what can I say you can use `synchronized` of your method, though it's impractical but it works. For a high load system (more traffic) can slow down your particular operation.

Comment: "synchronized" only works if you have one server instance. Having two instances of your server, it won't work.